# What is a standard way of importing XML data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I did some research on how to import XML data into MySQL possibly with the Workbench.

However, I was unable to find any easy tutorial how to do that. I have 6 XML files and all contain data, no schema.

From what I understood, the process consists of 2 parts:

1.Making the table (this is the part which is unclear to me) - is there a way to make the table from only XML data file?

2.Importing the data to the MySQL table. I think I understand this one, it could be done by executing this query:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml' 
INTO TABLE my_tablename(personal_number, firstname, ...);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need the ';' in the first line of your code "LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/pathtofile/file.xml';" ?

Comment: No I don't I added it there accidentally.

Comment: You could export an entire database as XML using MySQL(mysqldump --xml does this), but I think there isn't a way to do the reverse process (LOAD XML - mysql 5.5 only restores into a table). So you can't create tables from XML. But you could verify this [old link](http://rpbouman.blogspot.com.br/2010/04/restoring-xml-formatted-mysql-dumps.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it before where I read the XML files into a MySQL database where the data type was set to BLOB.